# How to properly handle InpuStream as a method argument

Tags: java

I've been googling for almost two days and i still can't figure it out. I have this exercise when it passes `InpuStream is` as an argument and expects me to store whatever is passed and return the count, but I don't know and can't seem to figure how to handle InputStream properly. I always get argument error.

Code:

```
class Subtitles {
    int redenBroj;
    int vrPocetok;
    int vrKraj;
    String text;

    public Subtitles() {
        redenBroj = 0;
        vrPocetok = 0;
        vrKraj = 0;
        text = null;
    }

    int loadSubtitles(InputStream is) {

    }

}
```

Comment: did you look at the javadocs for `InputStream` ?

Comment: @ScaryWombat I did but i only found examples only when file is used as input

Comment: I am assuming that `someone` is passing you an InputStream that is already open

Comment: Will you please add the error message you are getting when using the `InputStream` instance? Maybe you could also add your implementation of `loadSubtitles` method so we can see what didn't work.

Comment: @KaNa0011 That's what I'm asking I don't know how to implement it I've only tried `is = new BufferedStream()` and i get error `invalid arguments`

Comment: `BufferedStream` class is not a subclass of `InputStream`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`InputStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/io/InputStream.html) is an abstract class. Therefore, the implementation of the method `int loadSubtitles` should not care on how the given `InputStream` is implemented - it can be anything, as long as it is a type of `InputStream`.

You can choose from different subclasses of `InputStream` so that you can test your method with your own data format:

`FileInputStream` -- You can use this type of input stream if you want to stream a file:

```
File sourceFile = new File("source.txt");
InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(sourceFile)
```

`ByteArrayInputStream` -- This is used to stream an array of bytes.

```
byte[] input = "this is an example array".getBytes();
InputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(input);
```

Now that you have built an input stream, you can now use them regardless on how it is built:

```
// Java 9+
byte[] content = inputStream.readAllBytes();
// do something with `content`
```

-

```
// before Java 9
int data = inputStream.read();
while (data != -1) {
    // doSomething with `data`

    data = inputStream.read(); // read next data
}
inputStream.close(); // or use the try-with-resources syntax
```